# React app communicate with iframe via postMessage: where to setup callbacks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I have a website which communicates with a third party iframe.

There are 3 methods: login, sign and get information. They all work similar. I embed the third party iframe and send a message to it via `window.postMessage(...)` to it. After I have sent a message to the iframe I get back a response.

I can't come up with a clean architecture to encapsulate the communication.

Current idea:

```
class iFrameCommunicator{
  init() { 
      window.addEventListener('message', (message) => {
         if (message == "login_success"){
           setGlobalLoginState(true)
        }
        if (message == "sign_success"){
           setGlobalSignState(true)
        }
      })
    }
  }
  login() {
    window.postMessage({command: "login"})
  }

  sign(payload) {
    window.postMessage({command: "sign", payload: payload})
  }
}
```

Login page

```
<button onClick={() => iFrameCommunicator.login()}>Login</button>
```

With this approach I have to monitor the `GlobalLoginState` to see if the login call was successful. I would like the login function (and the other functions) to return a Promise instead.

Is there a way to refactor the code so that every function which communicates with the iframe returns a Promise without having to setup an `addEventListener` for every function call?

Answer (score 0):

So 3rd party iframe takes three messages, presumably you can't control what you get back?

However if you know what you are getting back on success / fail can you add a listener for the success / fail in your app - a bit flaky as its 3rd party and message may change, but that is what we do in a loader / iframe setup that we control.

Sending and listening for messages either side - we also pass a function into the iframe for invocation, but you can't given its not your iframe so callbacks presumably won't be possible.

What did you end up doing?

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered the usage of useEffect which depends on your GlobalLoginState?
Then updated your state based on other events? To be honest, it is quite very difficult to give an answer not knowing exactly the other context or availabilities within your webapp.